# Formation of planet

Tags: astronomy, planets

I was told that if we assume the formation of planet is due to the gathering/collapse of the cloud, we can use rotation period of a dust particle to determine if that particle will be attracted to the planet or the sun. That is if a particle is at a distance such that its rotation period is shorter than its period if it were rotating around the Sun, it will be attracted to the planet. Why is that? Thanks!

I try to derive in this way. If the dust particle is at a position such that its distance to the sun is $R_s$ and its distance to the planet is $R_p$, if it were to orbit around the sun, the velocity has to be $V_s=\sqrt{GM_s/R_s}$ and if it were to orbit around the planet, the velocity has to be $V_p=\sqrt{GM_p/R_p}$. And the period will be $T_s=2\pi\sqrt{R_s^3/GM_s}$ for orbiting around the sun and $T_p=2\pi\sqrt{R_p^3/GM_p}$ for orbiting around the planet.If $T_s>T_p$, then, $R_s^3/M_s>R_p^3/M_p$

I think it will be attracted to the planet if it has velocity $V$ such that $V_s<V<V_p$. And if $V_s<V_p<V$, it will fly away. But I cannot see how this is related to the inequality derived earlier.

Comment: I am sorry but it's not very clear to me what you are asking, partly because of the English-language mistakes. Perhaps you could proofread your question. If something is rotating around the sun at a particular orbit, the rotation period is determined by the radius of the orbit.

Comment: That is if a particle is **at a distance such that its rotation period is shorter that its period if it were rotating around the Sun**, it will be attracted to the planet. - distance from what?

Comment: I corrected some typos and add more explanation.